# Using Extracttext from cfpdf to get text of a pdf in coldfusion

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, ocr

Currently, I have a pdf that is not searchable and I am wondering what the best process is for preparing the file for coldfusion so I can index the file.

In particular, I am wondering whether a pdf file needs to be readable before using extracttext in cfpdf to pull the text from it.

I really appreciate the advice and I hope it helps other people who are interested in indexing pdf files with coldfusion.

I was considering extracting the text with Tesseract as suggested here

[Performing Optical Character Recognition on PDF's from ColdFusion using a Java or .NET Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496875/performing-optical-character-recognition-on-pdfs-from-coldfusion-using-a-java-o)

but if there is a built in feature in coldfusion, I would much rather use that and I think it would be more helpful to other people to know whether coldfusion can natively handle this task.

Comment: *using extracttext in cfpdf* What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Doing a simple test like the following did not produce any results.  <cfpdf action="extracttext" source="pdfs/test.pdf" name="myXML" />
<cfcontent type="text/xml" />
<cfoutput>#myXML#</cfoutput>

Comment: _Currently, I have a pdf that is not searchable_ - Have you tried using the builtin Solr search service? [See documentation here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WS2B335964-A0DA-4add-B9FE-4041464EC9E1.html)